# DebuggerDisplayAttribute with partial classes

Tags: c#, visual-studio, wcf, debugging, visual-studio-debugging

I have a WCF WebService that generates partial classes. Therefore I cannot put `DebuggerDisplayAttribute` on any of them, because it would be overriden at each update of the web service reference.

Can I have partial classes that define the `DebuggerDisplayAttribute` for some properties, just like for instance we can use `MetadataType` for view display in MVC?

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that changing the generated DataContract is a waste of time.

Luckily the classes are `partial` so you can have a second class file that holds logic that you need but doesn't get generated. You can annotate that partial class with the Debugger hints. For your scenario you'll need a [DebuggerTypeProxy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debuggertypeproxyattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) that holds a type you created to be instantiated by the debugger instead of the instance of your real class:

```
// namespace should match the namespace in your reference.cs
namespace MyCompany.MyApp.Service
{
    [DebuggerDisplay("Example")]
    [DebuggerTypeProxy(typeof(InternalProxy))]
    public partial class Example // name of your DataContract class in the reference.cs
    {
        internal class InternalProxy
        {
            private Example _realClass;
            // the debugger instantiate this class
            // with a reference to the instance being watched
            public InternalProxy(Example realClass)
            {
                _realClass = realClass;
            }

            [DebuggerDisplay("Description = {Proxiedproperty}")]
            public string Proxiedproperty {
                // description is a genereated property
                get { return _realClass.description; }
            }

                    // add other properties if needed
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I discovered that adding attribute like
`[DebuggerDisplay("{Property1}, {Property2}, etc.")]`
to the properly named partial class in respective namespace works even without this `InternalProxy` approach. Tested in .NET Framework 4.5.